# Puppeteer Failed to launch the browser process

Tags: javascript, puppeteer

When I use a code like this (an example off the website), an error message pops up {shown at the botton} which crashes the code however about a second later a blank google chrome page opens but nothing else happens because the code has crashed

```
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');

(async () => {
  const browser = await puppeteer.launch();
  const page = await browser.newPage();
  await page.goto('https://bbc.com');

  await browser.close();
})();
```

Error message is

```
Error: Failed to launch the browser process!
```

Comment: Did you try it with args: ["--no-sandbox"] ?

Comment: Yes i did, however that ran into the same error message

Comment: Are you running this code in a text editor?